# Comparing User Input To Integer

Tags: java, integer

I'm still in the learning part of Java. I've made a kind of guessing game. It looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class guessing_game {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Random generator = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        number = generator.nextInt(20);
        System.out.println("Guess the number!");
        game(number);
    }
    public static void game(int number) {
        int inputStorage;
        inputStorage = input.nextInt();
        if (inputStorage == number) {
            System.out.println("You've guessed the right number!");
        }
        else if (inputStorage != number) {
            System.out.println("Wrong number, try again!");
            game(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have a problem. My little sister and I played this "game". My sister was typing on the numpad. She accidently hit the + button before pressing enter and I got some errors. My question is: How can I let my application print a line which is saying that you can only input numbers and then restarts the game stub again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the input.nextInt() in a try catch statement and catch the exceptions that are thrown by input.nextInt(), InputMismatchException. A good tutorial for try catch statements is  [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) if you aren't sure what I am talking about.

```
try {
    inputStorage = input.nextInt();
} catch (InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.println("invalid type");
}
```

Another way you can do this is:

```
if(input.hasNextInt()){
     inputStorage = input.nextInt();
 }else{
      System.out.println("invalid type");
 }
```

There is also an error with continuing the game try using a while loop with a break if the number was guessed correctly:

```
int inputStorage;
boolean notGuessed = true;
while(notGuessed)
{
    if(input.hasNextInt()){
         inputStorage = input.nextInt();
     } else{
         System.out.println("invalid type");
      }
    if (inputStorage == number) {
        System.out.println("You've guessed the right number!");
        notGuessed = false;
    }
    else if (inputStorage != number) {
        System.out.println("Wrong number, try again!");

    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm a real beginner in Java, is it possible to change the not guessed boolean to guessed and set it to false by default? I'm not on my pc right now so I can't test it...

Comment: Yes this is possible, but you would have to add a logical or to the while condition: while(!guessed).

Comment: It doesn't work. When I enter a letter the "invalid type" text comes up and doesn't stop printing. It keeps going and going...

Comment: It's not supposed to stop until the number is correctly guessed. If you want a different condition then change the loop structure.

Comment: I made it print the invalid type text only once but I don't understand why it's working by now. http://pastebin.com/8m4WsV0T

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work the way I'd expect it. What is wrong with the way it runs?

Comment: Nothing. But with your way the code keeps printing the line over and over again. Like every ms the invalid type text.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is quite easy. You can accomplish it in various way.

Try this one

```
    public static int checkInt(String strNumber) {
    int Number;
    try {           
        Number = Integer.parseInt(strNumber);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        Number = -1;
    }
    return Number;
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
    public static int checkInt(String strNumber) {

    Number = Integer.parseInt(strNumber, -1);

    return Number;
}
```

The second one is even simpler because you omit a try catch block, that is rather not correctly used in such case. Read about the functions of Integer class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try/catch`:

```
boolean b = true;
while (b) {
    try {
          inputStorage = input.nextInt();
          b= false;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
          System.out.println("Invalid input.  Please enter again!");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error you got was an Exceptiion: `InputMismatchException`.

You can explicitly handle the exception using the Exception handling mechanism in java.

Read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm)

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

to know how it actually works.

Above suggested answers are exception handling only.